# Ninject not resolving to a configured singleton when resolving an interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an application that uses Ninject for its DI. I'm adding some new classes and they are not being resolved the way I think they should be.

I have a class `Foo` that implements an interface `ISomething`. If I configure the bindings like this:

```
kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Foo>();
```

and then do:

```
var foo1 = kernel.Get<Foo>();
var foo2 = kernel.Get<ISomething>();
```

the two variables have *different* instances of the `Foo` class.

If I change the binding to:

```
kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<Foo>());
```

and then do:

```
var foo1 = kernel.Get<Foo>();
var foo2 = kernel.Get<ISomething>();
```

the two variables have the *same* instance.

My understanding is that in the first case it should resolve the `ISomething` to `Foo`, which will in turn resolve to the singleton of itself. Is my understanding incorrect, or is something else wrong? It seems a bit redundant to have to manually resolve it.

Comment: Is it possible to do like this `kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Foo>().InSingletonScope();` and do you still get two instances?

Comment: I still get two different instances doing that.

Comment: Too bad. I was hoping Ninject would do some internal magic and resolve the same scope... but apparently that does not work that way.

Comment: @adrianbanks Your under standing it incorrect for Ninject. Those are two separate registrations, and thus two separate instance. The same approach happens with .net core whre you would also have to use the delegate factory `service.AddSingleton<ISomething>(_ => _.GetService<Foo>());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you omit the lifestyle in the registration, by convention, Ninject uses the transient lifestyle. This means that this:

```cs
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Foo>();
```

Is equivalent to:

```cs
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Foo>().InTransientScope();
```

With the addition of the lifestyle, it becomes easier to spot the problem:

```cs
kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Foo>().InTransientScope();
```

Or even more clearly:

```cs
kernel.Bind<Foo>()       .To<Foo>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Foo>().InTransientScope();
```

Here you see that you are registering `Foo` both as singleton and transient. This misconfiguration is a common pitfall called [Ambiguous Lifestyles](https://simpleinjector.org/diaal):

> When multiple registrations with a different lifestyle map to the same component, the component is said to have ambiguous lifestyles. Having one single component with multiple lifestyles will cause instances of that component to be cached in different ways and this can lead to behavior that you might not expect.

Some DI Containers do contain verification mechanisms that you can use to detect this kind of misconfiguration, but all DI Containers that I'm familiar with do allow you to accidentally misconfigure the container this way.